# How to create a multi client on one server system with fork() on c

Tags: c, linux, server, tcp, fork

Here is the code TCP/IP client – server. The program works like this, first is the client which connect with server and printf hello. The server on the another side if the connection has successfully done  printf a msg for connection with the port. So my question is how to use `fork()` function on server to create a multi clients system with one server.

```c
// client.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv [])
{
    int sock, i=1 ;
    char msg[SIZE],reply[SIZE];
    struct sockaddr_in addr; // Internet socket

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET; // Internet socket  opou exei thn oikogeneia address IP kai provides the communication of server-client 
    inet_aton(argv [1], &addr.sin_addr);  
    addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]) ) ; // metatroph byte pc se byte IP
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // Stream socket      kanei to connection  creat one " file descriptor  "  ppou omos den einai akoma etoimos gia thn epikinonia
    connect(sock, ( struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));   // the last step and the finally connection from one socket to another client-server
    
    prontf("hello");

    strcpy(msg,"") ;
    strcpy(reply,"");


    close(sock);
    return 0; 
}
```

```c
// server.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>


#define SIZE 1024
#define STR_SIZE 100 //STR_SIZE doesn't have to be a constant

int main(int argc, char *argv [])
{
    int psock, sock,cli_addr_len,i,j,res1;
    char msg[SIZE];
    struct sockaddr_in addr,cli_addr; // Internet socket
    char reply[SIZE];
    
    memset(&cli_addr, 0, sizeof(cli_addr));
    cli_addr_len = sizeof(cli_addr);

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET; // Internet socket
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); // All interfaces
    addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv [1]) ) ;
    psock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // Stream socket
    bind(psock, ( struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));  // assigning a name to  a sock
    listen (psock, 1) ;

    strcpy(msg,"") ;
    printf("\n waiting for new connection (port : %s) ... \n", argv [1]);
    sock = accept(psock, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &cli_addr_len);    //   accept and take request - sock from the queue to connection 
    printf("connection established...\n");

    close(sock);
}
```

Comment: why would you want to use fork? Creating a new process per client would be a pretty inefficient way to handle multiple clients on one server. At the very least use threads, not processes. You do this more or less the same. You get new socket fd from the accept, and then pass it to your new process or thread. Linux also offers polling, where you can query several sockets at once.

Comment: i want to creat with the fork() beqause is homework with that as prioritis .

Comment: [here](https://gist.github.com/oleksiiBobko/43d33b3c25c03bcc9b2b) is an example with threads. the interesting part is lines 58-71. At line 58 is the accept function that returns new socket descriptor. Then line 62  creates new thread and passes that socket descriptor to the handler. What you need is replace line 62 with forking new process and executing the handler in new process. [here](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/fork-in-c-programming-language/) is an example of a guide about fork.